# Proving LUB and GLB of a given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given set $A=\left\{\frac{1}{n}-(-1)^n|n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Calculate $\operatorname{inf}A,\operatorname{sup}A, \operatorname{min}A,\operatorname{max}A$ (if they exist)

**attempt**:
For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ $$-1<0-1<\frac{1}{n}-1\leq\frac{1}{n}-(-1)^n\leq\frac{1}{n}+1\leq 1+1=2$$
Showing $\operatorname{inf}A=-1$ which means $\forall \epsilon>0 \:\exists a\in A \,(\operatorname{inf}A+\epsilon >a)$
($n$ is even) There exists an even $n_0>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \iff ... \iff -1+\epsilon>\frac{1}{n_0}-1\in A$
(*)($n$ is odd) *that's where I struggle finding some $r$ s.t.* $-1+\epsilon>r>\frac{1}{n_0}+1$

Showing $\operatorname{sup}A=2$ which means $\forall \epsilon>0\:\exists a\in A\,(\operatorname{sup}A-\epsilon<a)$
*exactly the same struggle as* (*)

Comment: Try to create two subsets from the given set, one for even natural numbers and another one for odd. Hope you can proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to use the result that $$\sup (X \cup Y)= \max (\sup (X), \sup(Y))$$ $$\inf (X \cup Y)= \min (\inf(X), \inf(Y))$$

Your given set $A$ can be written as,

$$A=\left\{\frac{1}{n}+1: for \ odd \ n\right\}\bigcup \left\{\frac{1}{n}-1: for \ even \ n\right\}$$

Let $B= \left\{\frac{1}{n}+1: for \ odd \ n\right\}$ and $C= \left\{\frac{1}{n}-1: for \ even \ n\right\} $ which we can also write as

$B= \left\{\frac{1}{2k-1}+1: for \ k\in \mathbb N\right\}$ and $C= \left\{\frac{1}{2k}-1: for \ k \in \mathbb N\right\} $

Finding supremum and infimum of $B$ and $C$ is easy task.

Comment: Yes, but how do you prove that they're actually what they are?

Comment: @SlavikEgorov, can you find sup/inf for sets $A$ and $B$?

Comment: $\operatorname{inf}(\neq \operatorname{min})$ is $-1$, $\operatorname{sup}=\operatorname{max}$ is $2$. Finding them is easy, though how do you prove that for every lower bound $l$ we have $l\leq \operatorname{inf}$ and for every upper bound $u$ we have $\operatorname{sup}\leq u$?